# Can is_page and is_front_page both be true?

Tags: multisite, pages, templates

For some reason `is_front_page` isn't triggered on my subsite, running a child theme with its own header with a page set as a static home page under Reading.

I have this code in `header.php` to control which metatags to show on a post/page or on the frontpage, but only the `is_single` / `is_page` is printed.

```
<?php if (is_single() || is_page()) : if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- this is printed -->

<?php endwhile; endif; elseif(is_home() || is_front_page()) : ?>
<!--this is not printed -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

I was wondering if the `is_page` and `is_front_page` are cancelling each other out since they are both true when using a static front page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, if your site has a static page on the front, the condition `is_page` will be true and WP will never get to the `elseif`.

If you want a different template for your front page, you should exclude it from the first condition so it will return false in that case. Like this:

```
if ((is_single() || is_page()) && !is_front_page())
```

Or you can switch the statements around: first test for home/front and if that fails for single/page.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, we need to restructure that code a bit.